# Add PGP encryption to my opencart contact us page

Tags: encryption, opencart, opencart2.x, pgp

I am wondering if anyone can tell me or point me in right direction
of how to add PGP encryption to my opencart 2.1 contact us page.
(well maybe for all emails sent to admin)
so messages are encrypted using my public pgp key.

I already use SSL but would also like to use PGP aswell

I assume this can be added to code in mail function?